# Insert AUTOMATICALLY random string in username field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I want username field is automatically filled with this value:

```
username = str(n);
```

where `n` is a number (autoincremented or random).

I tried to add this in save method:

```
username = str(random.randint(0,1000000)
```

but there is a collision problem when `n` is the same for 2 users.

How do I do this ?

Comment: You could make a post-save signal and fill in the username from pk in it

Comment: Or you could turn username into a property equal to self.pk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate it
`username = str(random.randint(0,1000000)`
and check for a user with such a name
`User.objects.get(username=username)`
if you find someone, generate a new one.

```
def GenerateUsername():
    username = str(random.randint(0,1000000))

    try:
        User.objects.get(username=username)
        return GenerateUsername()
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return username;
```

Comment: it will result in stack overflow for 1000000 users

Comment: that's true. I didn't say that it is perfect, I've only answered his question :)

Comment: I didn't say you're wrong, I only say that an ordinary loop would be less memory-hungry in this particular case :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a modified version of the generate username method that allows you to create more human-readable usernames just in case you are using it as an identifier for any purpose.

```
from random import choice
from string import ascii_lowercase, digits
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def generate_random_username(length=16, chars=ascii_lowercase+digits, split=4, delimiter='-'):

    username = ''.join([choice(chars) for i in xrange(length)])

    if split:
        username = delimiter.join([username[start:start+split] for start in range(0, len(username), split)])

    try:
        User.objects.get(username=username)
        return generate_random_username(length=length, chars=chars, split=split, delimiter=delimiter)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return username;
```

Comment: +1 Thats a very nice solution, if the length has been reduced to 4 or 5 ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Based on Antony Hatchkins comments I implemented a similar algo recently, figured I'd post for feedback, looped with failure protection instead of recursive without protection:

```
def GenerateUsername():
    i = 0
    MAX = 1000000
    while(i < MAX):
        username = str(random.randint(0,MAX))
        try:
            User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return username
        i+=1
    raise Exception('All random username are taken')
```

Comment: You are not incrementing `i`